# Parsing in props value from parent to component and display

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Still new to ReactJS.

I have 3 JS pages: `Home`, `Create`, `Edit`.

From `Home`, you can navigate to the `Create` and `Edit` pages.
You can access the `Create` page anytime, but you need to call an API to populate some data before you can access the `Edit` page.

All 3 pages are using the same component, `FormEntry`. As its name, it generates basically a form input. Within this component, there are 2 functions: `Search` and `AddEdit`. `Home` is using the former, `Create` and `Edit` are using the later.

The flow is as such where when you click on the `Create` **button**, this will direct you to the `Create` **page**. The `Create` page will then display the form.

However, if you click on the `Search` **button**, this will call an API and generate data in a table. Each table row is clickable and clicking on them will direct you to the `Edit` **page**. For reusability, I parse in some values using `props` that, in theory, should populate the form fields based on which row I clicked on.

The issue I'm having is that though the value gets parsed in, **the form field is not displaying the correct data**. To be specific, the data from the `responseData` I parsed into the component is not displaying. And even if it does display, it's returning as 'undefined'.
What am I doing wrong?

**Home.js**

```
function HomePage() {
    const [responseData, setData] = useState([]);
    const navigateData = useNavigate();

    function navigateToEdit(event){
        navigateData({insert URL here}+event.id);
    }

    function getSearchData2(allData){
        ( allData.propRefNum !== "" || 
          allData.client !== "" || 
          allData.appSys !== "" || 
          allData.status !== "" ? AxiosCall.searchProposal(JSON.stringify(allData)): AxiosCall.getProposals()
        )
        .then(
            (result) => {
                setData(result.data);
            }
        );
    }


    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100%' }}>
                    <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                    <DataGrid onRowClick={navigateToEdit} rows={dataRowObjs} columns={dataColObjs} headerAlign="center"  disableColumnFilter />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default HomePage;
```

**Edit.js**

```
function EditPage()  {
    const [responseData, setData] = useState([]);

    const { id } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {

        const apiData = {
            id: id
        }

        AxiosCall.getProposal(JSON.stringify(apiData))
        .then(
            (result) => {
                setData(result.data);
            }
        );

    },[]);

    function getEditData(allData){
        fetch({insert URL here}).then(
            (result) => {
                setData(result);
            });
    }

    return <FormEntry.AddEditFormEntry title="Edit Proposal" defaultDataValue={responseData} responseInputData={getEditData} />
}

export default EditPage;
```

**FormEntry component; AddEditForm**

```
function AddEditFormEntry(props){
    const propRefNumRef = useRef();
    const descRef = useRef();
    const clientRef = useRef();

    const appSysRef = useRef();
    const statusRef = useRef();
    const remarkRef = useRef();
    const vendorRef = useRef();

    const { register, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();

    function submitData(data){
        //event.preventDefault();

        const propRefNum = propRefNumRef.current.value;
        const desc = descRef.current.value;
        const client = clientRef.current.value;

        const appSys = appSysRef.current.value;
        const status = statusRef.current.value;
        const remark = remarkRef.current.value;
        const vendor = vendorRef.current.value;

        const allData = {
            propRefNum: propRefNum,
            desc: desc,
            client: client,
            appSys: appSys,
            status: status,
            remark: remark,
            vendor: vendor,
        }
        props.responseInputData(allData);

    }

    let defaultRefNum = props.defaultDataValue?.refNum; - **Note A: this is the line in question. When I console.log this variable, it displays the data correctly**

    return(
        <>
            <form className="formEntry" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitData)}>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex'}} >
                    <div align="left" >
                        <RouterLink to={insert URL here} >
                            <IconButton aria-label="search" color="primary" >
                                <SkipPreviousIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                        </RouterLink >
                    </div>
                    <h1 style={{ flexGrow: 1, marginTop: -4 }} >{props.title}</h1>
                    <div align="right">
                        <IconButton aria-label="search" color="primary" type="submit" >
                            <SaveIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <IconButton aria-label="search" color="primary" type="submit" >
                            <SaveIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>

                <Stack justifyContent="center" direction="row" spacing={2} >
                    <Stack justifyContent="center" direction="column" spacing={2} >
                        <FieldEntry.TextEntry required="true" label="Proposal Reference Number" type="text" id="input_propRefNum" name="propRefNum" propsRef={propRefNumRef} value={defaultRefNum} /> 
**Referring to Note A above, I want to populate this field above. I am getting 'undefined', if not blank. If I am using the Create function, blank/undefined is expected. The Edit function is supposed to populate something here **
                        <FieldEntry.TextEntry label="Description" type="text" id="input_desc" name="desc" propsRef={descRef} value={props.defaultDataValue?.description} />
                        <FieldEntry.TextEntry required="true" label="Client" type="text" id="input_client" name="client" propsRef={clientRef} />
                        <FieldEntry.TextEntry required="true" label="Application System" type="text" id="input_appSys" name="appSys" propsRef={appSysRef} value={props.defaultDataValue?.appSystem} />
                    </Stack>
                </Stack>
                <br/>           
            </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Note: I've removed a number of codes that does not pertain to the matter, to keep the sample code small. Rest assured that aside from my issue, everything is working as expected**

I think a simpler example(which I just found out will have the same issue) would be

```
const [defaultRefNum, setRefNum] = useState("");
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
let testValue = props.defaultDataValue?.refNum

useEffect(() => {
        console.log("testValue2:",testValue)
        if (props.defaultDataValue != null){
            console.log("is not Null")
            setCounter(c => c+1);
        }
        else{
            console.log("is Null")
        }
    },[testValue]);
    console.log("counter:",counter)
```

and

```
<FieldEntry.TextEntry value={counter} />
```

console.log output - counter: 2

Value in TextEntry: 0

I would assume the value in TextEntry should've outputted to be 2.

Comment: `defaultDataValue` in `AddEditFormEntry` is `responseData` in `EditPage` which is an array, and based on this ***none*** of the `defaultDataValue` accesses in `AddEditFormEntry` appear to be valid. Is `AxiosCall.getProposal` updating state to be something *other* than an array? It's a bit unclear what to help with when your code is already a mish-mash of types.

Comment: @DrewReese ```AxiosCall.getProposal``` is a method call that calls my API. My API will then return a ```ResponseEntity``` or basically a JSON object with key-value data. This object is the ```responseData``` which is then parse to my EntryForm as a prop value, ```defaultDataValue```, where I can access the queried object's data  using the key; eg. ```props.defaultDataValue.refNum``` or ```props.defaultDataValue.status```. The help I'm needing is why the input field is **not** populating this data to the value, but when I hardcode ```value='Hello'``` this works. Keep getting 'undefined'

Comment: `props.defaultDataValue` is initially an empty array, as I said, so `props.defaultDataValue.refNum` is undefined, i.e. it's effectively this `[].refNum` -> `undefined`.

Comment: @DrewReese That is the case, yes, if you access the **Create** page. If you access the **Edit** page however, props.defaultDataValue returns an object. So, when I `console.log(props.defaultDataValue.refNum)`, this will return me a value. Anyway, I've updated the question with a simpler example of the issue I'm experiencing, so maybe that might be clearer?

Comment: In the simpler example what is the value of `props.defaultDataValue` and `props.defaultDataValue.refNum` such that we can reproduce the issue? Or can you provide a *running* codesandbox that does that we can just inspect and debug live? What is `FieldEntry.TextEntry` and how does it handle the `value` prop?